# Creating a button in jQuery Mobile with a custom icon

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on an app for a client and am trying to create a button with a completely custom icon. The icon is 30px x 30px and transparent in the middle.

I have almost achieved what I want using this css code:

```
/* info button override */
.ui-icon-info-page {
    background: url(images/G_help_icon_round.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

But there is a thin black circle that appears inside the icon, and also the icon image appears to be cut off:

[image]

I want to remove this circle and prevent the icon ? from being cut off. Also, I would like the question mark to be transparent instead of black, to show the image of the navigation bar beneath. If I try to set the background color to transparent though, the button appears entirely white:

[image]

How can I do this?

Update:

I tried applying this code:

```
/* info button override */
.ui-icon-info-page {
    background: url(help.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

And got this result:

[image]

I'm able to move the icon around by adjusting the top and left margins, but it's edges are cut off outside a frame centered on the black circle:

[image]

Update 2:

Here is the button I am using (Note that it is invisible here because it is a white button on a white background):

[image]

Here is the html code that I use to load the button:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
            <div><img border="0" src="images/G_iphone_navbar_logo.png" style="display:inline;"/> </div>          
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="fade" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a"></a>
            <a href="info.html" data-icon="info-page" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should fix the issue

```
/* info button override */
.ui-icon-info-page {
    background: url(help.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Please ensure you are loading your application css file after jquery mobile css.

Edit:Here is a sample code based on the code you posted with the issue fixed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #rightBtn .ui-btn-inner {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                margin: -3px;/*Modify to change icon position wrt the header*/
                border: none !important;
            }
            .ui-icon-custom {
                background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqicD.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
                background-size: 30px 30px;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                box-shadow: none;
                -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                margin: 0 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="fade" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a"></a>
            <a href="info.html" id="rightBtn" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a"></a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content"></div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

​A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/LCsmt/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't quite work. I've updated my question. I am loading the css for this page after the jquery mobile css (unless something is going on behind the scenes that I don't understand).

Comment: Any chance you can host the code somewhere with the actual icon you are using?.Then I can take a look and try to figure out the problem.Just need the code for the button alone.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you, but I think you are asking me to upload the button image. I added it to the question - note that it is not visible because it is a white button on a white background, but if you right click on the space in the question you will be able to save it. Thanks for your help!